# Product of Integral over General Region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given $f(x,y)=g(x)g(y)$ and $R=\{(x,y):a\le{x}\le{b}, c\le{y}\le{d}\}$, where $a,b,c,d$ are constants, prove the following result: $$\iint\limits_R{f(x,y)dA=\int_a^b{g(x)dx}\int_c^d{g(y)dy}}$$

So far I have $\int_c^d\int_a^b{g(x)g(y)dxdy}=\int_a^b{g(x)dx}\int_c^d{g(y)dy}$ and I am not sure how to further manipulate the left hand side in order to prove the statement. I have verified the statement using integer bounds and simple functions, but I am not sure how to proceed when it is arbitrary like this statement.

Comment: It seems to me that you have already solved the problem!

Comment: Look at the [Fubini–Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) for a complete statement of this result and an outline of the proof.

Comment: @Siminore Mike proved only that the iterated integral of the product of two univariate functions equals the product of the univariate integrals. The hard part is to show that the double integral over the area decomposes into the iterated integral.

Comment: There are books where the Riemann double integral is introduced by iterating integrals. I thought the OP had already seen how to reduce multiple integrals.